# Grouping different count queries into one result table

Tags: mysql

I wanted to aggregate or union together various count queries of this type.

```
mysql> select count(*) from lyra_eng_catalog where FILENAME like '%%lyra_2009%%' UNION select count(*) from lyra_eng_catalog where FILENAME like '%%lyra_2010%%';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      141 |
|     1681 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

It is doing a count of files in the database based on year. But could it be possible to have a column in the results table for each each to make it easier to read. Like a kind of report.

Thanks

Comment: Though I understand, what you mean - You should add the expected result to improve your question. This way other users with the same problem can see faster, that's it's exactly what they are looking for.

Comment: and it would be better to include the original table structure as well. I would agree with Thomas G answer but if you could prevent from typing the column value one by one and use what's in the original table structure, that would be better; e.g, if your `lyra_eng_catalogue` have a column for `year` , you should simply add `SELECT year,count(*) as count_result FROM .... UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a column with fixed values in your SQL queries to know what count are :

```
 select 'lyra_2009' as count_type, count(*) as count_result from lyra_eng_catalog where FILENAME like '%%lyra_2009%%' 
 UNION 
 select 'lyra_2010' as count_type, count(*) as count_result from lyra_eng_catalog where FILENAME like '%%lyra_2010%%'
;
```